# why my custom tld not accessible from /WEB-INF/lib/

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, taglib

In my web application I'd placed my `custom.tld` file in `/WEB-INF/lib/custom.tld` and referenced in my `web.xml` as

```
<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>customTldUri</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/custom.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

and if I do add `taglib` in *jsp* then I'm getting `JasperException` for not able to find/add referenced `tld`.

But if I do move the `custom.tld` to `/WEB-INF/custom.tld` and update the `web.xml` to `<taglib-location>/WEB-INF/custom.tld</taglib-location>` then it works.

But in the same project I do have *struts tld* files added in `/WEB-INF/lib/struts-*.tld` and there is not exception for them.

My question is why my `custom.tld` is not accessible if I do place it in `/WEB-INF/lib/` while the *strtus tld*s are working fine?